# UseExceptionHandler by Environment

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, exception, .net-8.0, exceptionhandler

How can I leverage the new error handling mechanism introduced in .NET 8 while distinguishing error injection handling based on the environment? Specifically, I want to handle errors differently during development and testing in one service, and in production in another service. Both services implement the IExceptionHandler interface.

Comment: Can you post minimal code?

Comment: Do you mean .NET 8 or ASP.NET 8?

Comment: what troubles you now? In .net 8 we have a new interface `IExceptionHandler` which can be implemented with different logic, what you need should be 2 implements, one for test and another one for production, you can change the dependency injection in Program.cs before publishing to production. Or you might checking the current environment in Program.cs and decide which implement should be injected.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-8.0#iexceptionhandler

Comment: Pls correct me if I misunderstood your requirement, I had a test in my side and all worked.

Answer (score 0):

Following the offcial document and I had a test with MVC project with Program.cs like below.

```
using WebMvcNet8;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment()) {
    builder.Services.AddExceptionHandler<CustomExceptionHandler>();
}
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
    
var app = builder.Build();    
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
else {
    app.UseExceptionHandler(opt => { });
}    
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();    
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();   
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");   
app.Run();
```

[image]
[image]